# div not displaying while hovering on the span

Tags: html, css

I have a following code snippet and I've got an issue while hovering on the span. The div with class `display` isn't showing while hovering the span. Here's the markup:

```
<span class="get">get</span>
<div class="display"></div>
```

And corresponding css:

```
.get:hover .display {
  display:block;
}

.display {
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: `.get:hover .display` selects all `.display` elements nested within an `.get:hover`. Your `display` is *not* inside an `get` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS adjacent selector

```
.get:hover + .display {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6qc6Lat/

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on CSS selectors and how they work. There are many good resources, and though a bit dry I'd still recommend carefully going through [the W3 selectors table](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) and their explanations. Here's an excerpt with the selectors you are using:

> `E F` => an `F` element descendant of an `E` element
>   `E:hover` => an E element during certain user actions
>   `E.warning` => an `E` element whose class is "`warning`"

The main thing to realize is that ***space* is in fact a selector**: the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). So your selector:

```
.get:hover .display
```

Will do, from *right to left*:

- Select all elements with class "`display`"...
- ...that are a descendant of...
- ... an element being `hover`ed...
- ... that also has class "`get`"

The problem you have is that your `div` is *not* a descendant of the hovered `span`. There are many ways to solve that, including [@dowomenfart's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28743237/419956) to use the adjecent selector, as well as changing your DOM nesting.